# Specifying starting point for graph traversal algorithm in neo4j

Tags: algorithm, graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to write an algorithm which will propagate values from a starting node to the entire connected component. Basically, if A receives 5 requests, and A sends 5 requests to B for each request A receives, B will receive 25 requests.

So basically, I'm trying to go from this

[image]

to this

[image]

I've written the following snippet in neo4j:

```
MATCH (a:Loc)-[r:ROAD]->(b:Loc)
 SET b.volume = b.volume + a.volume * r.cost
 RETURN a,r,b
```

But, what I don't know is how I am supposed to specify a starting point for this algorithm to **start**? It appears as if neo4j is updating the values correctly in this case, but I don't think this will work for a larger graph. I want to explicitly make the algorithm start propagating values from the START node.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there will be a better answer, and this approach has some limitations since some assumptions are made about the graph, but this works for your example.

Note that I added an `id` property to the `:Loc` nodes, but I only used it to select the start (and for printing the node `id` at the end).

```
MATCH p=(n:Loc)<-[:ROAD*]-(:Loc {id: 0})
WITH DISTINCT n, max(length(p)) as maxLp
ORDER BY maxLp  // order the nodes by their maximum distance from start
MATCH (n)<-[r:ROAD]-(p:Loc)
SET n.volume = n.volume + r.cost * p.volume
RETURN DISTINCT n.id, n.volume
```

And here's the result:

```
n.id    n.volume
1           4000
2         200000
3         200000
4       16400000
5      508000000
6    21632000000
```

The idea here was to get the longest paths to each node from the starting node.  These are ordered by "closeness" and then the volumes are updated in order of "closeness".

Comment: Thanks! This addresses one of my biggest issues - to have a generic query for all my use cases. :)

Comment: @bitnahian Just be careful with your graphs.  This will only update nodes connected (by some means) to your starting node. So, for example, if you had a large graph with disconnected subgraphs, and you wanted to "clock/step" the graph, you would need multiple steps using this technique.  Also, I doubt this will do what you want if you have a cyclic graph.

Comment: My graphs are acyclic. And the entire graph is one connected component so this should work fine at least for now.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, could you explain what ORDER by maxLp does?

Comment: @bitnahian  And even if this is the right way to approach the problem, I am pretty sure the cypher could be improved for efficiency and/or very large graph processing.

Comment: @bitnahian I updated the cypher with a comment.  I wanted to get the maximum distance (most hops) through the graph for each node from the start.  Then I wanted to order those nodes from closest to farthest to "sweep" through the graph in volume calculation order.

Comment: @bitnahian FYI, I updated the cypher to remove a couple of redundant lines.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the planner will use the labels to find starting places for the query (you can run an EXPLAIN of the query to see the query plan), so it's going to match to all :Loc nodes and expand the pattern and modify the properties accordingly.

This will be for all :Loc nodes, is that what you want, or do you only want this to apply for some smaller portion of your graph reachable from some starting node?

Comment: This would most likely be for the entire graph (but with different relationship labels for different use cases). However, I'd like for it to be more of a sweepline algorithm approach which would always hit my starting node first (which would vary for different use cases).